# How to use JQuery Week Calendar with generic weekday

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-week-calendar

I need to display a week using Jquery, but don't matter the "dates" for me.
I want Sunday/Monday.../Saturday

And then add "generic" events.

It's just a week plan with activities, but the date isn't important.

How can I do that?

Comment: can you elaborate more on what you want & what have you tried so far

Comment: I want to create a weekly plan, e.g.: On monday at 8 I have soccer, on tueday at 9pm I have class in college, and so on... The important is the WEEK view and not the date itself.

Comment: Go for `fullcalendar`. this may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some time, I ended up writing my own html table that would mimic the weekly calendar.
Then I assign the events to the correspondent cells.